# Using strtox for word generator ,

Tags: c

I'm trying to create word generator in C and found Segmentation Fault message.

> gdb output :
>
> ```
> _GI___strtok_r (
>     s=0x562d88201188 "some text without comma", 
>     delim=0x562d8820117f " ", save_ptr=0x7f570a47aa68 <olds>) at strtok_r.c:72
> ```

> code with strtox function :

> ```
>     char **words = malloc(sizeof(char *) * NUM_WORDS);
>     int num_words = 0;
>     char *save_ptr;
>     char *word = strtok(text, " ");
>     while (word != NULL) {
>
>     // Strip leading and trailing whitespace
>       while (isspace(*word)) {
>         word++;
>       }
>       int len = strlen(word);
>       while (len > 0 && isspace(word[len - 1])) {
>         len--;
>       }
>
>     // Allocate memory for the word and copy it using strdup()
>       words[num_words] = strdup(word);
>
>     // Move to the next word
>       num_words++;
>       word = strtok(NULL, " ");
>     }
> ```

how to use function with an indeterminate number of words in text?

Comment: CHATGPT couldn't handle a simple task?

Comment: `strtok()` will chop on diverse separators. Specify " \t\r\n" as the delimiter and save yourself from trying to "trim" whitespace... Beyond that there's more, right? Like "how big is NUM_WORDS???" is any 'given' number big enough to handle indeterminant input?

Comment: @Haris, Too many requests in 1 hour. Try again later.

Comment: @Fe2O3 That's the problem, I just added in argument  and counted the word count manually.

Comment: Your `while (isspace(*word)) {` loop and your `while (len > 0 && isspace(word[len - 1])) {` loop are superfluous when using `strtok()` with a `space` as the delimiter. Now it is valid for other whitespace characters, but that is trivially handled in `strtok()` by simply using `" \t\n"` (and any other wanted whitespace) as your delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe someone finally asked for this!

You may want to add verification that `realloc()` hasn't returned a NULL.

In brief, the string is chopped on the delimiters provided to `strtok()` while `realloc()` is used to grow an array of pointers to each of those segments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[] = "Once upon a time there lived a beautiful princess.", *p = buf;
    char **t = NULL; size_t sz = sizeof *t;
    int n = 0;

    while(!!(t=realloc(t,(n+1)*sz))&&!!(t[n]=strtok(p," .\n"))) p=NULL, n++;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        puts( t[i] );

    free( t );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Once
upon
a
time
there
lived
a
beautiful
princess
```

**EDIT**
Then there is the extension that can handle multiple input lines:

```
int main() {
    char *buf[] = { "Once upon a time\n", "there lived\n", " a beautiful princess.\n" };
    char **t = NULL; size_t sz = sizeof *t;
    int n = 0;

    for( int ln = 0; ln < sizeof buf/sizeof buf[0]; ln++ ) {
        char *p = buf[ln];
        while(!!(t=realloc(t,(n+1)*sz))&&!!(t[n]=strtok(p," .\n"))) p=NULL, n++;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        puts( t[i] );

    free( t );

    return 0;
}
/* Output same as shown above */
```

Put the `strtok()` as the parameter to `strdup()` and you've got yourself something that will preserve words while using a single line input buffer.

Comment: thanks,how to implement in the above code? or fix the generator?

Comment: My job is to point the way. You're going to have to supply a lot more details about what you are trying to "generate"... Chopping character arrays into segments is not generating anything. Usually when an OP offers a 'tiny glimpse' of a snippet of suspect code, the cause of a SEGFAULT is elsewhere...

Comment: My main code is like char word = function("text",num_words) and generate it with for loop.

Comment: There's no point in "describing" problem code you've written. Your description will, naturally, not include the actual problem... If you want others to "take a look", then post a minimum of code that others can compile and reproduce the problem. Otherwise, everyone's time is wasted making guesses...

Comment: only need change input char text[] = "some text" and use function(text,num_words),code worked well. :)